# ng-repeat behaving strangely with radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, haml

In my Angular app I use the `chosen` status of radio buttons to determine whether a 'confirm' button appears:

```
%label.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.btn-block
      %input{:type => "radio", :id => "option 1", :autocomplete => "off", :value => "Option 1", "ng-model" => "chosen"}  Option 1
%button.btn.btn-success.btn-lg.btn-block{"ng-if"=>"chosen"} Confirm: {{chosen}}
```

This works fine. However, when I use `ng-repeat` to generate the radio buttons, the confirm button no longer appears upon a button press

```
%label.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.btn-block{"ng-repeat" => "(key, ans) in currentTask.answers"}
      %input{:type => "radio", :id => "option {{key}}", :autocomplete => "off", "ng-value" => "Option {{key}}", "ng-model" => "chosen"}  Option {{key}}
```

**Edit** in regular HTML:

```
<label class="btn" ng-repeat = "(key, ans) in topic">
   <input type = "radio" id = "option {{key}}" autocomplete = "off" ng-value = "Option {{key}}" ng-model = "chosen">option
   </input>
</label>
<button ng-if="chosen"> Confirm: {{chosen}} </button>
```

Comment: It would be much easier for me to answer your question if it used plain old JS + HTML and provided an example in JSFiddle or similar.

Comment: put a line break before last ` Option {{key}}`, input shouldnt have child element.

Comment: @YOU {{key}} is only a number, not an html element

Comment: as far as I know if you put Option {{key}} beside `<input>`, it will be like  <input>Option {{key}}</input>, which is invalid html, Option {{key}} should be in side label tag, so putting Option {{key}} in next line is proper way.

Comment: @BenCr Couldn't replicate the problem, in a code snippet, but I've put up the code in regular HTML now

Comment: @You hmm I took that part out entirely and it still behaves the same